# How to render this array in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api

I want to show this advice from this API I have fetched all the data but when I try to show it, it throws the error, and also I tried to map the data but nothing works it shows errors

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [advices, setAdvices] = useState([]);
  console.log(advices); // you should have the fetch data here

  async function fetchData() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://api.adviceslip.com/advice');
      const data = await response.json();
      setAdvices(data.slip);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return <></>;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: It says that the data you want to show does not exist

Comment: @AryanRajput Please tell us the exact text of the error

Comment: You need to watch for a change in state using an effect hook: `useEffect(() => console.log(devices), [devices]);` You can't just log `devices` like that.

Comment: `You can't just log devices like that. `... why not @Andy? Of course there are cases where putting logging in a useEffect can be useful, but a log statement in the body of the component will work if you want to see every render.

Comment: @Andy I think we can log because the function starts over again when state is changed

Comment: before you actual jsx, you can write `if(!advices) return null`. This way, if advices is null, you will be returned immidiately and no error would be thrown

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect
} from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [advices, setAdvices] = useState([]);
  //advices will always be null here as initiated with empty array
  console.log(advices); // you should have the fetch data here 

  async function fetchData() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/Posts");
      const data = await response.json();
      setAdvices(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(advices);
  }, [advices]);

  return ( < > Test < />);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

the initial value of advice should be an object and there was not another serious problem
[codesand box link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-framework-dx2f6l?file=/src/App.js)

```
    import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [advices, setAdvices] = useState([]);
  console.log(advices); // you should have the fetch data here

  async function fetchData() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("https://api.adviceslip.com/advice");
      const data = await response.json();
      setAdvices(data.slip);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{advices.advice}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```